# Google-finance : How can I extract historical data in a defined date rance

Tags: google-finance

Im going to back-testing using goolge finance.
but it doesn't working.
How can i solve this problem.

Ticker : B2
Start date : B3
End date : B4

=googlefinance($B$2,"All","b3","b4","daily")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ne9B.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

=googlefinance($B$2,"All",b3,b4,"daily")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).